# Filtrar sólo si el campo no está vacío c#

Tags: c#, lista, linq

Buen día, estoy haciendo un método para devolver registros en `datatables.js`, parte de mi método, tiene la siguiente consulta:

```
var Roles = Ss.ListarSucursales().Where(
                x =>
                (x.NombreSucursal.IndexOf(searchColum, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) ||
                x.Ciudad.Nombre.IndexOf(searchColum, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                x.Colonia.IndexOf(searchColum, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
```

El método funciona, pero me di cuenta que, por ejemplo, si en algún registro el valor de `x.Colonia` llega como `NULL`, me salta un error por tratar de filtrar un campo null. Quisiera poder filtrar por ese campo, sólo si ese campo no está vacío. Normalmente para eso, utilizaría `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Colonia)` pero no sé como implementarlo en el bloque de código anterior.
¿Podrían ayudarme? de antemano muchas gracias :)

Comment: Saludos. Prueba para `x.NombreSucursal.IndexOf(...)` usar `(x.NombreSucursal??"").IndexOf(...)`y así para los demás casos.

Comment: Era justo lo que necesitaba! si quieres ponerlo para respuesta, te la aceptaré de inmediato :D solo pensando en que personas a futuro puedan buscar esta pregunta, explica el operador `??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando el operador `??`, de la siguiente forma:

la parte

```
x.NombreSucursal.IndexOf(searchColum, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

quede

```
(x.NombreSucursal??"").IndexOf(searchColum, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

lo anterior para cada una de las instrucciones que tienes como corresponda.

Lo que hace el operador `??` es que si lo que esta a su izquierda es `NULL` retorna el valor que pones a su derecha; tal que si `x.NombreSucursal` en cada interacción que sea `NULL` devolverá cadena vacía y en los casos que no devolverá el valor de `x.NombreSucursal`.

Este operador puede ser usado con cualquier tipo de dato; desde luego poniendo a su derecha un mismo tipo de dato al de su derecha, pues la derecha sería el valor por default; es decir si `x.NombreSucursal` fuese un entero sería `x.NombreSucursal??0` o si fuese un objeto `x.NombreSucursal??(new ElObjeto())`.

> Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si te entendí bien, este código te va a ser de utilidad:

```
var Roles = Ss.ListarSucursales()
            .Where(x =>
                (x.NombreSucursal.ToLower().Contains(searchColum.ToLower()) ||
                (x.Ciudad.Nombre.ToLower().Contains(searchColum.ToLower()) ||
                (x.Colonia.ToLower().Contains(searchColum.ToLower()))
            .ToList();
```

Lectura recomendada:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Hermano! :D tenía ese código en mente, pero en mi caso específico, necesito que sea indiferente a mayúsculas y minúsculas, por esa razón específica utilizo `IndexOf()` en vez de `Contains()`

Comment: haberlo dicho antes, voy editando

Comment: Hermano! :D @L.Ronquillo mira :D

Comment: Estoy leyendo al respecto, `Contains()` no tiene un método que tome un Stringcomparison como parámetro :(

Comment: Deja te agrego otra alternativa :D

Comment: muchísimas gracias hermano, creo que optaré por eso :D

Comment: Para servirles :D